# Can I get some clarification on the try catch finally concept? (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

So from what I've read, the try catch and finally concept is basically "Trying" a line of code and then "catching" an error. Then "finally", whether or not there is an error, execute a line of code that is within the braces of the "finally"? Please correct me if I am wrong. Any feedback is appreciated. I am reading from Programming in Visual C# 2008 (assigned to the class) and it doesn't really make sense to me.